# Русские символы не пишутся корректно в базу MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

Дано: Spring boot приложение + БД MySQL

Проблема: русские символы не пишутся корректно в базу
SSCCE: https://github.com/pazukdev/cyrillic-symbols-in-mysql..

Тестовая строка: "абв"

**application.properties:** spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true

**Результат:** в базе записано "???"

**application.properties:** spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=utf8

**Результат:** java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xD0\xB0\xD0\xB1\xD0\xB2'

**application.properties:** spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=utf8mb4

**Результат:** приложение падает на старте, база не создается, java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xD0\xB0\xD0\xB1\xD0\xB2'

**Выяснил следуюшее:**

1. Если попробовать вставить запись на русском в таблицу через консоль, то выдает ошибку: incorrect string value '\ xe9 x80". Т.е. настройки проекта можно исключить. Дело уже в базе.
2. В актуальной версии MySQL для таблицы по умолчанию  character set latin1 и collation latin1_swedish_ci
3. Если установить следующие настройки таблицы: alter table table_name convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci; , то записи на кириллице начинают нормально отображаться.
4. Но т.к. база создается при старте приложения и ее конфигурация прописана в spring boot application.properties (spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sovietboxers\?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true), то в таблицах character set и collation по умолчанию. Так что надо как-то задать такие же настройки, как в п.2, только в application.properties. То, что гуглится по этому поводу (useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=utf8) - не работает

PS Попробовал PostgreSQL: все пишется "из коробки". Но все равно хотелось бы настроить и MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, проблема решилась.

1. В application.properties в spring.datasource.url все-таки прописываем:

   useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=utf8
2. В /etc/mysql/*.cnf прописываем:

   [client]
   default-character-set = utf8

   [mysql]
   default-character-set = utf8

   [mysqld]
   character_set_server=utf8
   collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci

Статья, откуда взято, что прописать в /etc/mysql/*.cnf: https://medium.com/@manish_demblani/breaking-out-from-the-mysql-character-set-hell-24c6a306e1e5